# How to use scikit-learn PCA for features reduction and know which features are discarded

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca, feature-selection

I am trying to run a PCA on a matrix of dimensions m x n where m is the number of features and n the number of samples.

Suppose I want to preserve the `nf` features with the maximum variance. With `scikit-learn` I am able to do it in this way:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

nf = 100
pca = PCA(n_components=nf)
# X is the matrix transposed (n samples on the rows, m features on the columns)
pca.fit(X)

X_new = pca.transform(X)
```

Now, I get a new matrix `X_new` that has a shape of n x nf. Is it possible to know which features have been discarded or the retained ones?

Thanks

Comment: Feature are not discarded they are projected to smaller dimension and suppose to reveal interesting connections between the different features.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I was thinking PCA could be used for feature selection, but (correct if I am wrong) it is only used to rescale the data on the principal components. As you read it I think I'll close the question.

Comment: Your output matrix should be of shape `(n, nf)`, not `(nf, n)`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The features that your `PCA` object has determined during fitting are in `pca.components_`. The vector space orthogonal to the one spanned by `pca.components_` is discarded.

Please note that PCA does not "discard" or "retain" any of your pre-defined features (encoded by the columns you specify). It mixes all of them (by weighted sums) to find orthogonal directions of maximum variance.

If this is not the behaviour you are looking for, then PCA dimensionality reduction is not the way to go. For some simple general feature selection methods, you can take a look at `sklearn.feature_selection`

Comment: I finally understood what PCA does (hopefully). Is there any preferred correlation function to compute if a feature is correlated with a principal component? In this way I think to be able to find the most representative dimensions in my dataset.. (correct me if I am wrong) .. may I use just Pearson or cosine similarity?

Comment: Thumbs up for understanding PCA ;) -- In order to be able to answer your question, we need to be very clear about what is meant by *feature* and *dimension*. There is potential for confusion with both. The features you specified are the columns of your matrix. In order to see whether PCA component 0 makes use of feature `i`, you can compare `pca.components_[0, i]` to the rest of `pca.components_[0]`. So if I understand your question correctly, then the answer is to look at a given PC and see which of your features have the strongest weights.

Comment: Disclaimer: If you select features according to weights in your principal components you may or may not obtain something interesting. Once again, PCA is not made for throwing away features as defined by the canonical axes. In order to be sure what you are doing, try selecting `k` features using `sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest` using `sklearn.feature_selection.f_classif` or `sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression` depending on whether your target is numerical or categorical

Comment: Ok I'll take a look to those. To answer your previous question, I see components as pseudo-samples, is it wrong? I use feature and dimension interchangeably. However, in order to get k features (as a kind of feature selection), I think I have to swap samples and features, to obtain PCs that are pseudo-features (and not pseudo-samples). I do not know if it's clear. In this scenario I could correlate each feature with each PC, to see if it shows the same behavior across all samples. Thanks anyway for the effort :)

Comment: Ok, maybe another step forward: PCs are not pseudo-samples but arrays of projections of the features on each principal component. So, if I did it correctly, if some of the features are over a certain threshold together in a PC (e.g. A = 0.75 and B = 0.9), and not relevant in the other PCs (say A = 0.1 and B = 0.05), maybe we can say that they can be summarized with B (if our objective is feature selection)..

Comment: Guys, awsome discussion here, this was very interesting. Just to make sure @eickenberg, if I want to select the top 100 features that show highest weight on my PC1 (i.e. presumably the 100 most informative features) you'd then use `pca.components_[0,:100]` to select them?

Comment: Selecting `pca.components_[0, :100]` looks at the first 100 entries of the 0th row of that array. 0th row means first component, yes, but `:100` will just select you the weights on the first 100 features in the order you input them. If you wanted to assess the weights by their size/magnitude (unclear if this is a good idea) then to identify them you'd want to do `np.abs(pca.components_[0]).argsort()[::-1][:100]` (sort/argsort start at smallest, so either use `[::-1]` or an approprate keyword to invert, then cut off at 100). Remove `np.abs` if you want to keep the sign.

Answer (score 2):

The projected features onto principal components will retain the important information (axes with maximum variances) and drop axes with small variances. This behavior is like to `compression` (Not discard).

And `X_proj` is the better name of `X_new`, because it is the projection of `X` onto `principal components`

You can reconstruct the `X_rec` as

```
X_rec = pca.inverse_transform(X_proj) # X_proj is originally X_new
```

Here, `X_rec` is close to `X`, but the `less important` information was dropped by PCA. So we can say `X_rec` is denoised.

In my opinion, I can say `the noise` is discard.

Answer (score 1):

The answer marked above is incorrect. The sklearn site clearly states that the components_ array is sorted. so it can't be used to identify the important features.

> components_ : array, [n_components, n_features]
>   Principal axes in feature space, representing the directions of maximum variance in the data. The components are sorted by explained_variance_.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html

Comment: The `components_` array is sorted according to explained variance, which means that `components_[0]` is PC1, `components_[1]` is PC2, etc, from highest to lowest explained variance. If I understood correctly, what the answer above says is that you can use these to then select which input features have the highest weight on each of these PCs